# Do we keep appending new domains in the Google's disavow tool or Just add new entry every time?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, search-results, disavow-links

I keep getting tons of bad links every week for my domain.

My question is, As I find bad links every week, Do I need to keep appending the new bad links in disavow file or Just keep only a new finds in the file and then submit every week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your disavow file a database of all the URLs that you **'think'** Google is punishing your site for, you never delete existing URLS unless you think they will help, any new URLS that you **'know'** that are causing issues then you add the URL to your existing disavow, keeping all the previous URLS present...

***BUT!!! you shouldn't be updating your disavow on a weekly basis!***

You should not need to do a disavow update weekly, as it is considered perfectly natural for sites to gain low quality links on a regular basis, in fact it would be unnatural if you didn't. Google cares about 'BULK' links that are all found in a narrow time frame and are mostly off-topic to the page they are linking too, these are often in the thousands, not dozens or low hundreds.

***Diversity, and not referring to the UK street dancers***

If you are disavowing all links that you consider low quality then this can look suspicious, since your backlink profile should have good diversity, which includes nofollow and dofollow on a wide range of platforms. So, just because you consider a link to be no value, it could be contributing to keep your profile deserve.

***Google Ignores Low Quality Links***

Links that are low quality may be helping to keep your backlink profile deserve, those that are very spammy, or extremely low quality then Google has the ability to discount those links automatically, without any further intervention. So not only are you wasting time, you could be doing more harm that good.

***My advice?... Only every use disavow as a last resort***

Only ever use disavow in dire conditions when you are certain that you have received a automated or manual algorithmic penalty.

***Google's Advice on Disavow***

> [SOURCE](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en)
>
> This is an advanced feature and should only be used with caution. If
>   used incorrectly, this feature can potentially harm your site’s
>   performance in Google’s search results. We recommend that you disavow
>   backlinks only if you believe you have a considerable number of
>   spammy, artificial, or low-quality links pointing to your site, and if
>   you are confident that the links are causing issues for you. In most
>   cases, Google can assess which links to trust without additional
>   guidance, so most normal or typical sites will not need to use this
>   tool.

Answer (score 2):

[Google's disavow backlinks help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en) says:

> **Note: Uploading a new file will replace all previously uploaded ones.**

To add links you must append the links to your file and re-upload the whole thing.   If you only upload the newly found URLs, it will un-disavow all the previously submitted URLs.